# Generating array with N columns, with row sum equal to one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, matrix

I want to create a matrix (weights) with N columns, where the row sum should be equal to one.
With interval as a parameter too.
And I have to find the all possible set of values.

For example, if N = 3

```
interval = 0.01
weights = []
for i in np.arange(0,1.01,interval):
    for j in np.arange(0,1.01,interval):
        if i + j <= 1:
            weights.append(np.array([i,j,1-(i+j)]))
```

and if N = 4

```
interval = 0.1
weights_4 = []
for i in np.arange(0,1.1,interval):
    for j in np.arange(0,1.1,interval):
        for k in np.arange(0,1.1,interval):
            if i + j + k <= 0:
                weights_4.append(np.array([i,j,k,1-(i+j+k)]))
```

Is there any way to make it dynamic with N, and too in an efficient way?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you take into consideration decimal points, there will be infinite such combinations. @Akileshvar

Comment: with the interval being another parameter? @Vishnudev

Comment: What do you mean by intervals. Please clearly specify the inputs and expected output.

Comment: Because of how the problem is constructed, your time complexity always would be O(n!) where `n` is your number of columns. Your python code of course would be much slower because of using `append` method instead of list comprehension.

Comment: @Vishnudev please check the question again, I updated it. By interval I mean the decimal points.

Comment: @kacpo1 well, more than time complexity my real concern is to make it dynamic to `n` , so do you have any solution for that?

Comment: To make it dynamic to `n` you could use recursion.

Comment: What about negative nubers? In your current code there is possibility like `[0.9, 0.9, -0.8(?)]`

Comment: no only positive numbers @kacpo1

Comment: Any ideas for recursive implementation? @Vishnudev

Comment: So your code doesn't match those requirements because in the given example it would return negative number.

Comment: @kacpo1 nice catch, have to correct it, any suggestions over it?

Comment: `for j in np.arange(0,1-i,interval):` should limit sum of `i` and `j` to 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
interval = 0.1
weights = []

code=""
N=6
for line in range(N+1):
 if line<N:   
  code=code+" "*line+"for i"+str(line)+" in np.arange(0,1.1,"+str(interval)+"):"+"\n"
 else:
  somme=   ["i"+str(el)for el in range(N)]
  code=code+" "*line+"if "+ "+".join(somme)+"<= 0:"+"\n"
  code=code+" "*(line+1)+"weights.append(np.array(["+ ",".join(somme)+",1-("+"+".join(somme)+")]))"
print(code)
exec(code)
print(weights)
```

Comment: Hey, @Bahae El Hmimdi, I just ran you code, it generated only one array, and I went through the code, and the changed the `if condition` to `code=code+" "*line+"if "+ "+".join(somme)+"<= 1:"+"\n"` , then it worked well. I don't know if this is efficient way to do, but it does the job. Thank you so much.